# 20.04 after install of package python3-venv, pyvenv cannot execute (pointing to bad link)

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04

I'm a beginner when it comes to installing packages.  I know the basic `apt` commands.  Here's my problem:

I have an app that needs `venv` to operate correctly.  I couldn't find a package that installs `venv` but I did find a package for `pyvenv`.  So I executed this:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-venv
```

Now I have the file `/usr/bin/pyvenv` but it's a soft link to nowhere:

```
$ ll /usr/bin/pyvenv
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/pyvenv -> pyvenv-3.8
```

`which pyvenv-3.8` produces no output.  If I locate the file `pyvenv-3.8` I see this:

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/pyvenv-3.8
```

But that just points back to `pyvenv`.  So where should `pyvenv` be pointing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pyvenv` binary is [deprecated since 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

It seems like it's no longer built into the debian packaging for python3.8

The suggested command is to use `python3.8 -m venv ...` instead